# Grails app denied connection next day

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, grails

I wrote a web application using grails. It runs fine throughout the day however when I wake up and check it the next day it will not connect to the database properly without me reloading it. (MySQL). I feel as if the connection is being refused?

Here is my stack trace:

```
2014-07-28 13:28:07,103 [http-bio-8081-exec-93] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3345)
```

Here is my datasource:

```
dataSource {

// Production
driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
username = "ROOT"
password = "PASS"
dbCreate = "update"
url = "jdbc:mysql://172.16.1.3/work_orders_v2"
dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"

pooled = true
properties {
    maxActive = 50
    maxIdle = 25
    minIdle = 5
    initialSize = 5
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
    maxWait = 10000
}

}
```

Iv tried a few things that had no affect. Can you spot anything odd?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the connections in your pool are being closed by the database server after sitting idle.  This is normal behavior that I would expect to happen.

If you add these validation settings the connections in the pool will be tested before your code gets them.  Any closed connections will be dropped from the pool.

```
properties {
    maxActive = 50
    maxIdle = 25
    minIdle = 5
    initialSize = 5
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
    maxWait = 10000

    // Connection Validation Settings
    testOnBorrow=true
    testWhileIdle=true
    testOnReturn=true
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following properties which work fine for me.

```
            properties {
            maxActive = -1
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
            numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
            testOnBorrow=true
            testWhileIdle=true
            testOnReturn=false
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState"
         }
```

Comment: I never messed with the production modes.. This is my complete data source and I use the grails command wizard and just create a war file then deploy that to tomcat. Is there a special way that I should make it production? I cant see this being the problem though..

Comment: Just checked and running grials war automatically sets it for production

Comment: Sure I will give your properties a try, May i ask why max active is -1?

Comment: The properties I provided are the default ones generated by grails version 2.3.5. maxActive=-1 means allow unlimited connections Active in the pool. Though I haven't faced any database connection issue with these settings, I am not sure what the implications are for these properties.